# Apache Stanbol Sentiment Analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, apache-stanbol

I am trying to get the sentiment tags for a given text in Apache-Stanbol .

I have added the "sentiment-word-classifier" engine to a enhancer chain, i have also added all the required chains to be able to extract the tokens and their parts of speech tags.

This is the composition of my enhancer chain :

```
langid ( required , LangIdEnhancementEngine)
opennlp-sentence ( required , OpenNlpSentenceDetectionEngine)
stanford-nlp ( required , RestfulNlpAnalysisEngine)
opennlp-token ( required , OpenNlpTokenizerEngine)
opennlp-pos ( required , OpenNlpPosTaggingEngine)
sentiment-wordclassifier ( required , SentimentEngine)
opennlp-chunker ( required , OpenNlpChunkingEngine)
pos-chunker ( required , PosChunkerEngine)
```

This is the sufficient input for sentiment-word-classifier right??
Still am not getting any sentiment tags.
Can somebody throw some light on what i am missing ??

Thanks

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? Actually I am using stanbol to do sentiment analysis, but I don't know where to start. I have well launched the server at localhost, what's next? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sentiment analysis needs two engines to be included

- sentiment-wordclassifier
- sentiment-summarization

The sentiment-wordclassifier classifies tokens with sentiment values (based on dictionaries entries of a language). NOTE that you will also need to provide those dictionaries (see the modules under [`data/sentiment`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stanbol/branches/release-0.12/data/sentiment/)). Results are stored in the AnalyzedText content part.

The sentiment-summarization uses those classifications to create sentiments for phrases, sentences and the whole documents. Summarization does consider negations and also ties to assign adjectives holding a sentiment to the correct noun or pronoun. The result of sentiment-summarization are added to the Enhancement Results as `fise:SentimentAnnotation`

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Started out with a chain which had just the sentiment-wordclassifier engine and was getting nothing. Then spotted in the stanbol/logs/error.log a helpful message about analyzed content not getting to the sentiment engine and a suggestion to include opennlp-pos. Looked at the other chains and included opennlp-sentence, opennlp-token in addition to the opennlp-pos. Was still getting nothing. Then came across your question and the mention of the data/sentiment module. Changed to the data/sentiment/sentiwordnet folder and did mvn install -DskipTests -PinstallBundle -Dsling=http://your.stanbol.com:8080/system/console. Am now seeing sentiment output and trying to make sense of it.